# How to get notified when a file is uploaded in ftp location using Azure and start copy job?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-triggers

I need to start a copy job whenever a file(desired) is uploaded in an FTP location. so for notifying that the file is available in that location is there any way( like if the file is available then run this copy job) other than logic apps using ADF? can anyone please post some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Azure DataFactory event based triggers will not support FTP. So we cannot do directly from Azure DataFactory.

As you said, you might need to relay on other process such as logic apps or Azure functions or Azure Automation, etc. to check for file landing on FTP and kick off ADF pipeline execution.